# write an array in latex

Tags: arrays

I am unable to write this matrix in latex in a full width page. The matrix is given in the below link. Please help me to write this matrix in latex.

[image]

**Edit:**
Thanks for your feedback. I did the following syntax, but unfortunately I am not able to get the output within a page. Help me.

```
\[\begin{array}{*{9}{c}} 
{1+\Delta t\theta } & {\rho _{,x} \Delta t} & {\rho_{,y} \Delta t} & {0} & {\rho \Delta t} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{\left(uu_{,x} +vu_{,y} \right)\Delta t} & {\rho +\rho u_{,x} \Delta t} & {\rho u_{,y} \Delta t} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{\left(uv_{,x} +vv_{,y} +\frac{1}{2\varepsilon {\kern 1pt} {\rm Fr}} \right)\Delta t} & {\rho v_{,x} \Delta t} & {\rho +\rho v_{,y} \Delta t} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{\left(uT_{,x} +vT_{,y} +\frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} v}{2\varepsilon {\kern 1pt} {\rm Fr}} \right)\Delta t} & {\left(\rho T_{,x} -\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} p'_{,x} \right)\Delta t} & {\left(\rho T_{,y} -\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} p'_{,y} +\frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} \rho }{2\varepsilon {\kern 1pt} {\rm Fr}} \right)\Delta t} & {\rho } & {-\frac{8}{3} \frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} }{Re} \theta \Delta t} & {-2\frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} }{Re} \omega \Delta t} & {0} & {0} & {-\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} } \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} 
\end{array}\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What have you tried?

Comment: `\[\begin{array}{*{9}{c}} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \end{array}\]`. instread numbers insert your math expressions. (now are so small that are not readable) . for more, you need to show, what you try so far.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Given single letter names to the longest expressions,

Answer (score 3):

[image: Output from the Tex file]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
{1+\Delta t\theta } & 
{\rho _{,x} \Delta t} & 
{\rho {,y} \Delta t} & 
{0} & 
{\rho \Delta t} & 
{0} & 
{0} & 
{0} & 
{0} \\ 
{\left(uu{,x} +vu_{,y} \right)\Delta t} & 
{\rho +\rho u_{,x} \Delta t} & 
{\rho u_{,y} \Delta t} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{\left(uv_{,x} +vv_{,y} +\frac{1}{2\varepsilon {\kern 1pt} {\rm Fr}} \right)\Delta t} & 
{\rho v_{,x} \Delta t} & 
{\rho +\rho v_{,y} \Delta t} & 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
X &
Y & 
Z  & 
{\rho } & 
W & 
{-2\frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} }{Re} \omega \Delta t} & 
{0} & {0} & 
{-\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} } \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {1} & {0} \\ 
{0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} & {0} 
\end{pmatrix}
\]
where
\begin{align*}
X
&=
{\left(uT_{,x} +vT_{,y} +\frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} v}{2\varepsilon {\kern 1pt} {\rm Fr}} \right)\Delta t},
\\
Y
&=
{\left(\rho T_{,x} -\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} p'{,x} \right)\Delta t},
\\
Z
&=
{\left(\rho T{,y} -\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} p'_{,y} +\frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} \rho }{2\varepsilon {\kern 1pt} {\rm Fr}} \right)\Delta t},
\\
W
&=
{-\frac{8}{3} \frac{\left(\gamma -1\right){\rm M}^{2} }{Re} \theta \Delta t},
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice solution! OP use unusual and also obsolete notations:  `\left(uv_{,x}` , `{\rm M}` and all curly braces around each cells are surplus ...